# Detect end of file transfer with javascript

Tags: javascript, download

Is it possible to detect - via Javascript or a different way - when a file transfer (browser downloading a requested file) is actually really complete?

If the browser requests a file, e.g. through an Ajax call, the success message (status 200, readystate 4) comes already before the file has actually been downloaded. But I need to know, when the transfer itself is completed. Any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to check if an image is completly loaded:

```
var newImage;

newImage = new Image();
newImage.onload = function() {
    var domImg;
    domImg = document.getElementById('my_img');
    domImg.src = this.src;

    domImg.width = this.width;
    domImg.height = this.height;
}

newImage.width = <img width>;
newImage.height = <img height>;
newImage.src = <your source>;
```

Edit: 
Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTJWu/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Marvin. I should specify that the file to be transfered is not an image but a font-file (.eot, .svg, .ttf or .woff) and that the file transfer is not initiated by a manual ajax call but "automatically" by the browser, when a dom element is updated to use a font, which is up to that point not used anywhere on the page. Any Idea how to track that?

Comment: Maybe this thread could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312323/how-to-know-if-a-font-font-face-has-already-been-loaded

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. The problem with all the scripts out there is that they usually test the width of spans containing a text periodically. Running intervals like that is pretty massive on the work-load side. I am trying to come up with a solution on my own I guess, until the w3c releases the font-load api.