# How can I detect whether a web font is loaded and hide text nodes until that happens?

Tags: javascript, font-face

Webkit handles the time before a web-font (@font-face) loads by hiding the text nodes. But not all browsers do this, some show a standard font until the font loads, which I want to avoid. I want to show my page elements, but hide all text nodes until the webfont is loaded.

Can I do this with JavaScript?

I'd like to do it without a 3rd party library so I can learn how it's done.

Comment: The good Mr. Irish went on about this once: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/

Answer (score 1):

This question can be answered if you google a little bit more ...

[Answer can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12316349/4241030)

jQuery font-spy allows to handle what happens when a font is not loaded yet or is damaged

[Original Repository](https://github.com/patrickmarabeas/jQuery-FontSpy.js)
[Demo Fonts](http://patrickmarabeas.github.io/jQuery-FontSpy.js/)