# textbox causing issue with font in fabric js

Tags: javascript, css, fabricjs

I am adding simple `text` element in fabric js using this code,

```
var t = new fabric.IText("Hello world !", {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    fill: '#000000',
    fontSize: 25,
    top : 50,
    left:50
});
canvas.add(t);
```

And its working perfect, Now issue when i am adding font in style like this,

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display);
</style>
```

Then adding `textbox` into canvas using fabricjs like this,

```
var t = new fabric.IText("Hello world !", {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    fill: '#000000',
    fontFamily:'Playfair Display',
    fontSize: 25,
    top : 50,
    left:50
});
canvas.add(t);
```

With font applied,
But when i click on texbox within canvas, you can see textbox has issue like this `http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f05taz2f3`. but this happens only when you load page first time or force reload page with `ctrl+f5`.
Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tkworx7/) second time it loads perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The font hasn't been fully loaded by the time you add the text. Which means fabric is determining the width of the element based on the default font instead of your webfont.

You could wait until the font has loaded before adding to the canvas. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312323/how-to-know-if-a-font-font-face-has-already-been-loaded) has some answers on how to do this properly.

Comment: tried that, but seems not working still. getting same issue. any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2612) on Fabric's GitHub repo and it is assumedly being worked on.