# google material icons loading slowly, flicker from text to icon

Tags: reactjs, material-design

Installing Google Material icons using [Setup Method 2 self hosting](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/) for our React project the ligatures associated with the icon is sometimes displayed before the material icon.

```
<i class="material-icons">face</i> {/* shows text "face" on site prior to proper material icon load */}
```

For example the above line would display "face" for a second before showing a face.  How can we delay the UI rendering until the file references are fully loaded?

```
/*material icons file references loaded locally */
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Material Icons';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url(../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
      src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), url(../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'), url(../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'), url(../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called **preload.js** in your **src** folder.

```
document.fonts.load('10pt "Material Icons"').then(function () {
  console.log('Material Icons font has been preloaded.');
});
```

add the following script tag at the end of the **head** section in **index.html**

```
<script defer src="%PUBLIC_URL%/preload.js"></script>
```

user in your React component like this

```
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';

 function MyComponent() {
   return <Icon>home</Icon>;
 }
```

I hope it's working

Answer (score 0):

just use a "preload" with link tag as :

```
<link rel="preload" href="./material-symbols-outlined.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer from [How to prevent material icon text from showing up when Google's JS fails to convert them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710834/how-to-prevent-material-icon-text-from-showing-up-when-googles-js-fails-to-conv):

you can use `font-display: block;`, just add this CSS to your HTML head:

```
<style>
   @font-face {
      font-family: 'Material Icons';
      font-display: block;
    }
</style>
```

for more information [font-display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display)