# Mat-icon shows text Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm using mat-icon and on some browsers, the mat-icon shows the text instead of the actual icon or it can show the text until the icon is being imported. I tried to import:

`@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';`

to my style.css but it didn't solve the issue. Is there a way to prevent showing the text until icon loaded or even not showing text at all?

````
import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatOptionModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatAutocompleteModule
} from '@angular/material';
import { ScrollDispatchModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { UniquePipe } from './pipes/unique/unique.pipe';
import { ConfirmCountryComponent } from './dialogs/confirm-country/confirm-country.component';
import { AutocompleteComponent } from './components/autocomplete/autocomplete.component';
import { ConfirmCountryService } from './dialogs/confirm-country/confirm-country.service';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatOptionModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    ScrollDispatchModule,
    UniquePipe
  ],
  entryComponents: [XXX],
  providers: [XXX],
  declarations: [XXX, XXX, XXX],
  schemas: [XXX]
})
export class AngularMaterialModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: AngularMaterialModule,
    };
  }
}```
````

Comment: what browsers??

Comment: According to this example:https://stackblitz.com/angular/aalakaknjdkj?file=src%2Findex.html try to use this link in the `@import` :`https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons&display=block`

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to your index.html:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

instead of this:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
```

Comment: Oddly enough, doing the opposite of what you suggest fixed the problem for me.I had been using the link, but switching to @import is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

There are answers on [gitHub](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12171), i just cite the simplest solution.

> There's a really straightforward fix for this.
>
> If you self-host your material icons (which I recommend doing with all
> your fonts) https://google.github.io/material-design-icons # Setup
> Method 2. Self hosting
>
> You'll find 2 css snippets of @font-face and .material-icons In the
> @font-face css add font-display: block like this
>
> ```
> @font-face {
>   font-family: 'Material Icons';
>   font-style: normal;
>   font-weight: 400;
>   font-display: block;
>   ...
> ```
>
> This will stop the font from showing anything until it loads.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using WebFontLoader (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47115200/1250830) related question).  The main concept is WebFontLoader applies various css classes to the HTML element as the font is loading or if the font fails to load.

Here's the steps I took to get it set up:

1. Install WebFontLoader using `npm i webfontloader`.  See the library in NPM [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfontloader).
2. In my base app component, I implemented the OnInit event handler:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    //this applies webfont css classes to material icons while they are loading
    var WebFont = require('webfontloader');
    WebFont.load({
       google: {
          families: [
             'Material Icons',
          ],
       },
    });
  }
```

Note:  WebFontLoader allows you to hook into any of the fonts that you're loading in your app.  The Material Icon fonts are just the primary concern here.

3. I added this bit into my base app component's css:

```
//this allows us to hide the unstyled text while the icons are loading
::ng-deep .wf-loading, .wf-materialicons-n4-inactive {
  .material-icons {
    display: none
  }
}
```

Note:  The `::ng-deep` selector allows us to apply the styling in the sub components of the app.  For my project, I figure I'd do it at the base component and not have to worry about styling the individual components that used material icons.

Cheers!