# How to catch when was loaded my material icons?

Tags: javascript, icons, google-material-icons

I am using these icons fonts of Google:
https://material.io/icons/

I am developing a web extension and some web pages like Github is blocking my icons, I am trying to check with vanilla js if the font is available or not, the problem here is that I don't know when I need to confirm if the font was loaded or not.

I am using a setTimeOut but I really hate this method.

My code:

```
function confirmFont(view) {

     setTimeout(function(){
         if(!document.fonts.check("12px Material-Icons")) {
             .....
         }
     }, 2000);

 }
```

I tried with document ready and window load but this is not working I need to be more specific.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312323/how-to-know-if-a-font-font-face-has-already-been-loaded?

Answer (score 3):

If you already use `document.fonts`, why not use the [`Events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet#Events) that come with that interface? As a `loadingdone` event is fired whenever a font face set has finished loading, you could actually use an event listener to check your fonts. Below is a working example:

```js
!function() {
    // Setting up listener for font checking
    var font = "1rem 'Material Icons'";
    document.fonts.addEventListener('loadingdone', function(event) {
        console.log(`Checking ${font}: ${ document.fonts.check(font)}`);
    })

    // Loading font
    var link = document.createElement('link'),
        head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    link.addEventListener('load', function() {
        console.log('Font loaded');
    })

    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
    head.appendChild(link);
}()
```

```html
<i class="material-icons md-48">face</i>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this in the following way:

```
document.fonts.ready.then(function () {
    if(!document.fonts.check("12px Material-Icons")) {
        ...
    }
});
```