# FontAwesome not loaded correctly with Angular elements

Tags: angular, fonts, font-awesome, angular-elements

I have an Angular app that is packaged using Angular Elements and then loaded into another web application. I am using Font Awesome but icons are being displayed as boxes.

Similar to what is described in [How to know if a font (@font-face) has already been loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312323/how-to-know-if-a-font-font-face-has-already-been-loaded)

I have added [fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome) through npm.

Also I added the following to my angular.json

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
]
```

This is how I am using FA.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-bars">
  {{ label }}
</button>
```

So my question is what am I missing here? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of manually configure font-awesome in the angular project please use NPM package, which will auto-configure everything for  you in few simple steps

Please refer this like/npm document 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome