# Icons from fontawesome locally stored appearing as boxes

Tags: html, css

Here's the folder directory:
[File Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40J8Y.png)

And here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Comic Web</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/brands/fontawesome.css">     
</head>
<body>
   <footer>
      <div class="footer-contact">             
            <ul class="contacts">
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com"></a><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>                  
                <li><a href="https://mail.google.com"><i class="fab fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>                    
                <li><a href="https://github.com"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>         
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what's wrong with it although I already follow the guide indicated on the website. Thank you!

Comment: Well from experience i have observed boxes appear when either font had not loaded as yet but page rendered (depending on font type some browser might show blank or some might show boxes). Also do check in network console that fonts are loaded

Comment: one way forwarded is run onload on window and run everything from there. That at least gives enough blink time as things load in parallel to each other since fonts are in head somewhere they would be fetched ahead

Comment: check if this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/12316349/10588650

Comment: @Syed, Thanks for the input though. I'll be checking on the reference link you provided. However, I might figure this out late, I am not much of a technical person in this field yet hahaha. Anyway, thank you, and have a nice day ahead!!!